# How to make faster group by in mysql very big table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have got tables in MySQL like thoose:

```
troll_id     troll_family_id    troll_name    troll_birth_timestamp
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1            1                  Kamil         100000
2            1                  Bartek        200000
3            2                  Maciek        100000
4            2                  Andrzej       200000

troll_family_id    troll_family_name
------------------------------------------
1                  Trollowski
2                  Trollowicz
```

I want get `only one the youngest Troll from every famillies`

so I want to get rows like that:

```
troll.troll_name
-----------------    
Bartek
Andrzej
```

I have got few millions of trolls in DB, I tried query like that:

```
SELECT troll.troll_name 
FROM troll 
GROUP BY troll.troll_family_id 
ORDER BY troll.troll_birth_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 0, 50
```

But it freezes my response for http. So I do not even know, is this query correct.

Comment: Does your table use indexes?

Comment: Try adding indexes to your table if there are no indexes

Comment: Yes, in troll_id and troll_family_id and troll_birth_timestamp

Comment: troll_id is a PK, so it is already indexed. troll_name is most important. Because after selecting all matching trolls engine can create a inmemory table and use it to execute further processing.

Comment: Don't do all rows, but select: `WHERE troll_birth_timestamp < '???'`

Comment: Should I Use SELECT DISTINCT troll.troll_family_id instead of my query?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.troll_name 
FROM troll a 
INNER JOIN (SELECT troll_family_id, MAX(troll_birth_timestamp) AS troll_birth_timestamp 
            FROM troll 
            GROUP BY troll_family_id
           ) AS b on a.troll_family_id = b.troll_family_id AND a.troll_birth_timestamp = b.troll_birth_timestamp
LIMIT 0, 50
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is (fairly) meaningless

Answer (score 0):

Slight Changes to your existing query. ORDER BY works after GROUP BY:

```
SELECT troll_family_name, t.troll_name 
FROM
(
  SELECT troll_family_name, t.troll_name 
  FROM troll t
  JOIN troll_family tf ON tf.troll_family_id=t.troll_family_id
  ORDER BY t.troll_birth_timestamp DESC      
)temp
GROUP BY troll_family_name
LIMIT 0, 50
```

More over add indexes to tf.troll_family_id, t.troll_family_id

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX` function on groups

```
SELECT troll.troll_name, MAX(troll_birth_timestamp) AS troll_birth_timestamp
FROM troll 
GROUP BY troll.troll_family_id 
LIMIT 0, 50
```